# Makefile automatic variable @F doesn't get expanded in dependencies

Tags: makefile

In the following Makefile `$F` doesn't get expanded and it's just empty. I am wondering what is an elegant solution to use `@F` instead of writing dependencies explicitly?

```
nested-cycles.scala first.scala follow.scala : ../$(basename $(@F)).aps ${APS2SCALA}
    ${APS2SCALA} ${APS2SCALAFLAGS} -S $(basename $(@F))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right.  See the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-automatic-variables-in-prerequisites):

> It’s very important that you recognize the limited scope in which automatic variable values are available: they only have values within the recipe. In particular, you cannot use them anywhere within the target list of a rule; they have no value there and will expand to the empty string. Also, they cannot be accessed directly within the prerequisite list of a rule. A common mistake is attempting to use $@ within the prerequisites list; this will not work.

The usual way this is handled is to write a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html) telling make how to build a target matching a given pattern, based on a prerequisite using that pattern.  For your example it would be something like this:

```
%.scala : ../%.aps ${APS2SCALA}
        ${APS2SCALA} ${APS2SCALAFLAGS} -S $*
```